# Why is my flex checkbox itemrenderer updating the wrong datasource?

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, checkbox, datasource, itemrenderer

I have two tile lists that draw data from an array collection assigned to a datagrid:

```
<mx:TileList dataProvider="{myDatagrid.selectedItem.myColumnOne}">
 <mx:itemRenderer >
  <mx:Component>
   <mx:CheckBox label="{data.label}" selected="{data.selected}" click="{data.selected = this.selected}" />
  </mx:Component>
 </mx:itemRenderer>
</mx:TileList>

<mx:TileList dataProvider="{myDatagrid.selectedItem.myColumnTwo}" >
 <mx:itemRenderer >
  <mx:Component>
   <mx:CheckBox label="{data.label}" selected="{data.selected}" click="{data.selected = this.selected}" />
  </mx:Component>
 </mx:itemRenderer>
</mx:TileList>
```

These tile lists are not in the datagrid - they are in an edit form.

Both myColumnOne & myColumnTwo have similar data:

{label: foo; selected: true}
{label: bar; selected: false}
etc...

The checkboxes populate properly when data is loaded into the grid.  The problem is that when checking/unchecking, if the same label shows up in both myColumnOne & myColumnTwo, both columns are updated instead of just the one that was clicked.

Is there any code change that would make this behave properly?

Comment: IT sounds like myColumnOne and myColumnTwo are two different variables pointing to the exact same value.  But, we can't tell based on the small snippet you showed us.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is they must be referencing the same underlying object, you need to clone the objects used for the dataProviders for the list, just having two different collections doesn't mean that the objects in the collections are different (this is good for memory performance, but not good for your case).  So wherever you populate myColumnTwo and myColumnOne you have to actually do a "deep copy" of the objects that are being put into there or else they share memory.  A deep copy in terms of AS3 would mean create a new Object (could be strongly typed if that's the case) and copy all the properties from the original object to the new clone.

Also you may want to consider actually putting the item renderer definitions in their own mxml, I tend to have issues with understanding the scope when doing them inline this way, whatever benefit you think you're getting from doing it this way is probably not worth it.

Comment: Check into UIDUtil http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/UIDUtil.html .  You need to implement IUID to make objects with identical properties appear to be different objects in Lists (because the Lists will check UIDUtil to see if they are the same, and if they look the same UIDUtil will say they are). Stupid, but it's what we have.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship Good to know thanks for the extra info, I've seen problems similar to this when the same object is repeated within a lists dataprovider but I thought if we created a new object and copied the properties even if the properties matched 100% it would end up treating them separately due to the memory address allocated for each, but in looking at that doc it would seem the hex values I was seeing in the debugger were probably actually the uids instead of memory offsets which is what I was assuming.